# Wide vertical spacing in Explorer in Windows 11

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

After upgrading to Win 11 this is how file dialogs look:

[image]

This is a 'Save as' dialog but you can see this in Explorer windows as well, either in *List* or *Details* view.

Is there a way to reduce the spacing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to reduce the spacing?

Yes (the wide spacing can be annoying).

Open Windows File Explorer.

Three dots ... upper right.

Select Options.

Folder options comes up. Select View Tab.

In the first section, check (enable) Decrease space between items (Compact View).

This works in Windows 11 Production and Insider.

[image: Decrease File Explorer spacing]

.

You can see in the background of the screen shot that my item spacing is quite tight, which is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Far less scrolling....

Comment: Yes.  I did this right away on Windows 11

Answer (score 1):

John's answer is one I have been repeating at lot, almost like a parrot. Another way, though I wish we had an Options setting for this, is to click the current folder name in the file path ribbon after the folder displays. This will narrow the displayed spacing between rows, which is especially apparent when we have extra large icons displayed. Of course, we might still see wider gaps further down the listing until all the folder members have been displayed at least once. I think this has to do with File Explorer initially assuming the largest possible icon before it processes each row, so members can be displayed faster.